# pdfmake + angularjs passing variables

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, pdfmake

I have this code inside my angular controller, I took pdfmake dynamic table code from [here](https://github.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/issues/24)
I want to pass json response to table function inside var dd, but it says it's undefined, I tried console.log(jsontopdf) directly inside .success() and it works, so json is correctly passed through API...
what I did wrong?

```
  $http.post('/cambio', toElab)
         .success(function(data) {
          jsontopdf = data;

          var dd = {
             content: [
                 { text: 'Dynamic parts', style: 'header' },
                 table(jsontopdf, ['a', 'b','c'])
             ]
         }


        function table(data, columns) {
            return {
                table: {
                    headerRows: 1,
                    body: buildTableBody(data, columns)

                }
            };
        }

        function buildTableBody(data, columns) {
          var body = [];

          body.push(columns);

          angular.forEach(data, function(row) {
              var dataRow = [];

              angular.forEach(columns, function(column) {
                  dataRow.push(row[column].toString());
              })

              body.push(dataRow);
          });

          return body;
      }


         });
  }
```

Comment: what is undefined? jsontopdf, table or dd?

Comment: Sorry, I was confused cause I tried so many things, with this setup says something like can't apply toString() to noto define

Comment: * to not defined...If I separe code and take dd, table and buildtablebody out of .success, says jsontopdf is undefined..

Answer (score 0):

OK, I figured it out, my Json comes from a Jackson ArrayNode, i made it work by applying JSON.stringify and than JSON.parse on var jsontopdf...

There is some kind of more sensed conversion that I missed?